# need to loop through the number of records and increase the $y var by 6

Tags: php, tcpdf

I need to loop through the number of records and increase the `$y` variable by 6 for each record starting at `30.5`. I have tried this but it will not work :

```
for ($i = 30; $i < $n ; $i += 6) {
$n //number of records
$y = 30.5;
$pdf->SetXY (10, $y);
}
```

Comment: You're not increasing `$y` anywhere in the code. Did you forget `$y += 6`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make slight change to your code:

```
$y=30.5;
for ($i = 30; $i < $n ; $i += 6) {
//$n this should be deleted
$y=$y+$i;
$pdf->SetXY (10, $y);
}
```

Comment: And perhaps also remove that `$n //number of records` comment